# Jetpack Compose BasicTextField placeholder blocks getting a focus when clicked

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, focus, textfield

I use Jetpack Compose BasicTextField and set the placeholder using Text component like this:

[image]

And when I click the placeholder text, the textfield does not get a focus for it.

Is it a bug on Compose or is there any workaround?

The code is this:

```
                    BasicTextField(
                        value = "",
                        onValueChange = { input ->
                        },
                    ) { innerTextField ->
                        TextFieldDecorationBox(
                            value = "",
                            innerTextField = innerTextField,
                            placeholder = {
                                Text(
                                    text = "place holder"
                                )
                            },
                        )
                    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add the enabled parameter?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti thanks for your answer. Yes I added enabled param.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the same interaction source for both the outer and inner text fields.

```
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }

BasicTextField(
    ...
    interactionSource = interactionSource
) { innerTextField ->
    OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.DecorationBox(
        ...
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
    )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but may be you forget to invoke `innerTextField()` function inside `decoration box`, Check the below code

[image]

```
@Composable
fun BasicTextFieldDesign() {

    var name by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(horizontal = 20.dp),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        BasicTextField(
            value = name,
            onValueChange = {
                name = it
            },
            decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .border(
                            width = 2.dp,
                            color = Color(0XFF4c8acc),
                            shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)
                        )

                ) {
                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(15.dp)
                    ) {
                        Icon(Icons.Outlined.Person, contentDescription = "")
                        if(name.isEmpty())
                        Text(text = "Enter name")
                        // you have to invoke this function then cursor will focus and you will able to write something
                        innerTextField.invoke()
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however I updated my question by adding the code, could you please have a look again? I am not sure where I need to call innerTextField.invoke() in the code base?

Comment: instead of calling `TextFieldDecorationBox` you can create custom things inside `decorationBox`, you can refer my answer @mooongcle

Comment: Do you have any idea for TextFieldDecorationBox?

Comment: i never used `TextFieldDecorationBox`, i prefer to make custom things , you can try my answer and customise according to your need.